# Customizing the Rendering of a Zend_Form_Element_Radio

Tags: php, oop, zend-framework, zend-form

I have an object that's an instance of a Zend_Form_Element_Radio.  I'd like to customize how these radio buttons are displayed.  The [manual](http://framework.zend.com/manual/en/zend.form.standardElements.html) remarks

> Radio elements allow you to specify several options, of which you need a single value returned. Zend_Form_Element_Radio extends the base Zend_Form_Element_Multi class, allowing you to specify a number of options, and then uses the formRadio view helper to display these.

However, I'm not picking on the context of a HOW the formRadio helper should be used, and how that would allow me to customize the display.

Before I dig too deeply into the Zend source, is there something obvious I'm missing, and/or a straight forward explanation of the intended use?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I did a bit of misreading there.  Objects instantiated from `Zend_Form_Element_Radio`
have a property named `$helper`, which defaults to `formMyhelper`.  This property determines the name of the helper that a `Zend_Form_Element_Radio` will use while rendering itself.

Comment: Yeah you are correct, if you want to modify how you are displaying the radio buttons then just write yourself a new helper class (they aren't very hard) and use that instead either by wrapping a new class around the Zend_Form_Element_Radio (My_Form_Element_Radio) or changing the helper when instantiating the element (not that great an idea as you will need to do it over and over and over)